# Endeca baseline failed as 'permission denied' in renaming the Dgraph log file

Tags: endeca, oracle-commerce, endeca-workbench

I am getting error in baseline update when Dgraph log folder is renamed. I guess this is because Dgraph is not properly stopped before rename and log folder is locked.

**Below is the error from backup_log_dir_for_component_Dgraph2.log file (Filepath PlatformServices\workspace\logs\archive)**

---

```
Renaming G:\Endeca\MyEndecaApp\config\script\..\..\.\logs\dgraphs\Dgraph2 to G:\Endeca\MyEndecaApp\config\script\..\..\.\logs\dgraphs\Dgraph2.2016_06_28.06_02_42
Unable to rename G:\Endeca\MyEndecaApp\config\script\..\..\.\logs\dgraphs\Dgraph2 to G:\Endeca\MyEndecaApp\config\script\..\..\.\logs\dgraphs\Dgraph2.2016_06_28.06_02_42: Permission denied
```

How can I resolve this, as error is intermittent, baseline sometimes run successfully and next time it fails due to log folder locked by Dgraph.

I searched and found there is a Dgraph property named **'numIdleSecondsAfterStop'** which is the number of seconds baseline waits before renaming the log folder after Dgraph stops, this is to ensure that log file locks are release by the component before proceeding.

**How can I change this property?** When I am changing this directly from App.config file, it is not reflecting in IAP workbench.

Comment: `Permission denied` error says that the folder (or the parent folder(s)) are not having sufficient write permission.  Can you check all the way upto the Endeca app that it has full write permission?

Comment: This link has an example for `numIdleSecondsForStop`: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29586_01/webhelp/dt_usage/src/cdt_dgraphs.html